# Do I need to file taxes when selling on eBay or Amazon?

Tags: united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax, online, ebay

I'd like to sell my own camera gear (for a total of less than £4k) on eBay UK or Amazon UK.

Since I'm not a business and I am losing money (I would sale for less than what I bought it for), I thought filing taxes would not be necessary, but I'm no expert about UK tax regulations and I could not find much.

Answer (score 6):

> In simple terms, it is a business operation when it becomes a
>   profit-making enterprise.
>
> It is a grey area, but there is a difference between selling
>   occasional personal items on eBay and selling for profit.
>
> I would imagine the sort of considerations HM Revenue & Customs would
>   take into account are the size of your turnover, the extent to which
>   you are both buying and selling, and whether you are clearly
>   specialising in one particular commodity as opposed of disposing of
>   unwanted presents or clearing the loft.

http://www.ebay.co.uk/gds/When-does-eBay-selling-become-taxable-/10000000004494855/g.html

I don't believe that you selling your personal camera gear will be taxable, but as the link says, it is a grey area.

They also recommend to do this

> It's far better than having to deal with an investigation a few years
>   down the line.
>
> When it comes to completing your tax return, there is a section which
>   is headed "other income", and it is here where you will enter the net
>   earnings from the web business.
>
> "Net" here means your additional income, less all expenses associated
>   with it.

If you are still worried

> I would always encourage people to take a cautious approach and discuss their position with HMRC via its helpline on 08454 915 4515.

Comment: "Profit-making enterprise" is key. If you bought something, used it, and are now selling it for less than you bought it, it is loss-making. And hence OP doesn't need to declare it as income.